# HTML float number field with high precision but renders rounded value

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an accounting/inventory system. The users expect the numbers  to be rounded to 2 decimal places. Of course this much rounding causes a lot of discrepancies between different parts of the system.

I wanted to know if there is a way to render the number inputs rounded  to 2 decimal while keeping the high precision number to avoid rounding errors.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're working with money, you need to avoid native JavaScript numbers entirely. Work with a fixed-point math library, or do the computing in some server-side language that has fixed-point math.

Comment: @pointy or just calculate everything in pennies

Comment: @nathanhayfield yes but things still get weird when you perform division. Fixed-point libraries have "banker's rounding" that can be trusted.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, will check it out.

Comment: @pointy I have had pretty good luck with: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/

Answer (score 1):

I think your safe bet is to use a library like https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/ that allows you to use fixed point arithmetics, avoiding foating pont issues and be close to accounting rules (things like do your sums with 5 digits of precision and so on)